# Make ball move away from ball on click

Tags: javascript, click, coordinates, move, direction

There are some questions similar to this one and I have read them all but what I need is of a very specific nature.

Essentially I have a ball with a round area around it that can be clicked.
When you click this area, the ball should move in the direction opposite to the direction of the click compared to the center of the ball. So if you click right under the ball it should move up. 
I have managed to this this by using the following

```
function clickBall(event){
    //finding position of click

    var rect = document.getElementById("theBall").getBoundingClientRect();
    var ballX=rect.left-294.8641870117188;
    var ballY=rect.top-60.125;

    click[0] = event.clientX-313.999593505859423; click[1] = event.clientY-79;         

    distanceX=ballX-click[0];   console.log(distanceX);
    distanceY=ballY-click[1];   console.log(distanceY);

    ballMoving=true;
    ballPosition = click;

    //document.getElementById("theBall").style.left=(ballX+distanceX)+"px";
    //document.getElementById("theBall").style.top=(ballY+distanceY)+"px";
}
```

moveBall gets called by update which runs every frame

```
    function moveBall(){

    if(ballMoving){
        moveTime-=1;

        if(moveTime<0){  //control move time
            moveTime=ballMoveTime;
            ballMoving=false;
        }

        ballPosition[0]+=distanceX/150*moveTime;
        ballPosition[1]+=distanceY/150*moveTime;

        ballSpeed-=ballSpeedReducion;
        checkCollision();

        document.getElementById("theBall").style.left=ballPosition[0]+"px";
        document.getElementById("theBall").style.top=ballPosition[1]+"px";
    }

}
```

sorry about all the weird numbers i had to do some adjustments, but anyways.

The problem with this is, it makes the ball move away from the click point, but if you click really close to the ball, it moves just a little, and if u click as far away as u can inside the blue area, it moves way too much.

I tried to solve this by having if statements that find if X and Y are positive or negative and makes them 1 or -1 accordingly, but this makes them only be able to move diagonally...

I need a way to make it so it moves just as much no matter how far the click is from the ball. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, can you check https://jsfiddle.net/j9c12mka/181 . If you hover over the outer circle, do you want the ball to move to the end of the red line? The thing is - if I understand you correctly - i think you would need some basic geometry ("a way to make it so it moves just as much no matter how far the click is from the ball."). (The example is with svg, but I can give another example if you're more specific)